# About Elements of a Vector Space, and Line Segments between them

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

I need complementary explanations for some basic definitions I encountered during introductory Geometry works.

My first question:

> Given $V$ any vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$, when we cite any element $P$ of $V$, does it naturally define a vector $OP$? or does it define just a point in the Space?

My second question:

> When we speak of line segments, e.g. $t_1 P_1 + t_2 P_2$ with $t_1 + t_2 = 1$ where $t_{i=1,2}$ are scalars, has this line segment any sense of orientation it implies in the Space?

Thanks.

Comment: Throw away your knowledge about the point $ O $. If $ P $ is an element of $ V $ then $ P $ is what we call vector. We can add vectors and multiply them by elements of the field.

Comment: Usually people mean just the set of points when they say line segment.

Comment: so that line segments needn't to have any orientation right?

Comment: For any vectors $ v, u $ the line segment between $ v $ and $ u $ is the same as the line segment between $ u $ and $ v $.

Comment: @CrabMan ok, thank you

Comment: You might note that  your definition of "line segment" isn't quite right - if $P_1\ne P_2$ then what you define is the whole _line_  containing $P_1$ and $P_2$.  To get the line _segment_ you need to add the restriction $t_i\ge0$. (**Hence** the notion of  "line segment" is undefined in a vector space over an arbitrary field, since $t_i\ge0$ is meaningless.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich by **an arbitrary field**, do you mean any other Field with different topology? e.g. the field may not be linearly ordered and the set may not be dense with regards to the ordering defined?

Comment: By "an arbitrary field" I just mean any field at all. You _started_ by saying $V$ is a vector space over a field $\Bbb F$; since you didn't put any restrictions on $\Bbb F$ you're talking about "an arbitrary field". ("with different topology" - no, in fact in general a field doesn't come with any topology at all.)

Comment: So would it be better to specify that $\mathbb{F} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$? I want to be sure the point you want to make.